# Please explain what a co-product actually does or means (in the context of Hopf-Algebra)

Tags: lie-algebras, tensor-products, hopf-algebras, clifford-algebras

Studying some Hopf Algebra in the context of mathematical physics. Looking at it as a generalization/extension of Tensor Products, Lie Algebra or Clifford Algebra.

Despite this being my n-th attempt, I fail to understand what a co-product actually does or means. Sure, it somehow *co*mplements the product, but in which sense?

**Any hints to examples where it is actually possible to follow what's going on?**

**Any simple explanation/insight I am missing here?**

Comment: Do you want to understand it categorically? Or just practically? I think the categorical notion of co-product is unintuitive without understanding some classical examples of coproducts.

Comment: Are you familiar with coproducts vs. products in simpler categories?

Comment: Please no categories. I can somehow, faintly grasp the general picture there, but this does nothing for any practical understanding. I am not familiar with any coproduct, because I always fail to get it's 'practical' meaning.

Comment: I suspect that "coproduct" here is referring to the _comultiplication_ of a Hopf algebra and so the comments above are irrelevant.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh that's quite likely, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @EricWofsey It adds to my confusion that there seems to be a fundamental difference!? Care to quickly elaborate on that?

Comment: @DoctorNuu Think about groups. We can use the word "product" to refer to the group operation of a specific group ($"g\cdot h$"), or to refer to the direct product of two groups ("$G\times H$"). Basically the difference is: are you working inside a single group and combining two elements to get a third element of that group, or are you combining two groups to get a third?

Comment: Similarly, in the Hopf algebra case the distinction would be between the comultiplication operation inside a single Hopf algebra and the coproduct of two different Hopf algebras (actually I can't recall if the category of Hopf algebras has coproducts, but ignore that for now).

Comment: Yeah, I should probably start another rant about the unimaginative or rather confusing naming of things ;-) *This question is about a single algebra, however*

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Math.SE!

This might sound dumb at first, but you should really view the coproduct as the dual of an 'ordinary' multiplication in the following sense: If $A\otimes_k A\to A$ is an associative multiplication over a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space $A$ , it dualizes to a map $\Delta: A^{\ast}\to (A\otimes_k A)^{\ast}\stackrel{\cong}{\longleftarrow} A^{\ast}\otimes_k A^{\ast}$, where the last isomorphism crucially relies on the finite-dimensionality of $A$.

How does that look like concretely? Assume for simplicity that $A$ has a multiplicative basis $\{e_i\}$, that is, $e_i e_j = e_k$ or $e_i e_j=0$, for some suitable $k$ depending on $i,j$. Then you can check that $\Delta$ maps $e_i^{\ast}$ to $\sum_{e_j e_k = e_i} e_j^{\ast}\otimes e_k^{\ast}$. In other words: The comultiplication describes all ways to *decompose* a (basis) element as a product of (basis) elements.

You can look at $A=k[x]/(x^n)$ for example and you'll see that $\Delta(x^k) = \sum_{a+b=k} x^a\otimes x^b$ corresponding to the decompositions $x^k = x^{a+b} = x^a x^b$. Note that the same example works with the full polynomial ring $A=k[x]$, when treating it as a graded vector space and using graded duals - in this case, you only need degree-wise finite-dimensionality.

But you see the issue with finite-dimensionality if you try something like $A=k[x^{\pm 1}]$: You have infinitely many decompositions of a single element, e.g. $1 = x x^{-1} = x^2 x^{-2} = ...$. Capturing all these would require an *infinite* sum of elementary tensors, which isn't defined in the ordinary tensor product.

Finally, note that *if* you have a comultiplication, you can in fact always dualize it to a multiplication, since the map $A^{\ast}\otimes_k A^{\ast}\to (A\otimes_k A)^{\ast}$ always exists. In that sense, you can see a comultiplication as a more restricted, 'finite' notion of a multiplication.

Comment: I like the 'concrete' part with the $e_i$. I like the idea of decomposition (although I don't see why it should be a sum). If, at this point, you could elaborate on what the actual use (and sense) of this decomposition is, that would probably answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Should have asked myself: "Have I googled it?" Easy game. A quick search for '**Hopf Algbra**' and '**practical**' lead to the brilliant [Hopf Algebras in General and in Combinatorial Physics: a practical introduction](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.0249.pdf)

A real-world application of the coproduct for describing 'algebraic' composites. This almost exactly matches the hunch I had.